# Collecting all rows from a database

Tags: java, arrays, database

I'm trying to retrieve all the values stored in a database where it matches the sensor name.

The code runs however, it only outputs the final value in the database.

```
String info = "test info"
String sensorNameStr = "test sensor name";
String sensorValueStr = "test sensor value";

String selectSQL = "select sensorvalue from sensorUsage where "+
    " sensorname = '" + sensorNameStr + 
    "' order by TimeInserted asc";

String retrievedSensorData = "no data available";

try {       
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        retrievedSensorData = rs.getString(1);
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error in SQL " + ex.getMessage());
}

String json = "{\"sensor\": {\"" + sensorNameStr + 
              "\": \"" + retrievedSensorData + "\"}}";

System.out.println("DEBUG: json return: "+json);
```

Do I have to create a for loop so all values are returned and outputted on a webpage? As that's how I am viewing the data without manually going into the server. Also, if I do this, is it possible to only receive the last few inserted sensor values?

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: You already have a loop. But at each iteration, you overwrite the previous value stored in retrievedSensorData by the next one. Store all values in a list, and transform that list to JSON. You also really need to learn about prepared statements (think about what will happen if the name contains a quote, for example). And you should also use a JSON mapper like Jackson rather than generating JSON by yourself, and once again failing to escape special characters.

Comment: Not related to your problem but you have to close the Connection/PreparedStatement/ResultSet or you will leak DB resources (on most DB drivers).  Use try-with-resources to automatically close them (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query you retrieve only rows from column `sensorvalue` and all belong to specific `sensorname`. There are no other condition.
So it should be easy to make an [Json with the Java EE API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsonp003.htm)

```
// ...
JsonObject model = null;

try
{
    // ...
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    JsonArrayBuilder jsonArrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    while(rs.next())
    {
        jsonArrayBuilder.add(rs.getString("sensorvalue"));
    }

    JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    jsonObjectBuilder.add("sensorvalues", jsonArrayBuilder);
    model = jsonObjectBuilder.build();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}

response.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");

StringWriter stWriter = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(stWriter);
jsonWriter.writeObject((JsonObject) model);
jsonWriter.close();

response.getWriter().append(stWriter.toString());
```

The output should be something like:

> {"sensorvalues":["1","2"]}